# What's the difference between gitcmd.exe and cmd.exe?

Tags: git, cmd.exe

I use Windows and my question is: what's the difference between `git-cmd.exe` and `cmd.exe`?

I tried to run some tools on both and  `git-cmd.exe` seems better and seems a bit faster, why?

Answer (score 3):

> what's the diference between git-cmd.exe and cmd.exe?

They are absolutely different applications. In other words, they have nothing in common. `git-cmd.exe` is a bootstrap tool initializing `PATH` and some other environment variables let you ready to use git-for-windows. Well, **by default** it runs `cmd.exe` as shell, but the shell may be changed via `--command=...` switch.

> i tried to run some tools on both and git-cmd.exe seems better

Unconfirmed statement. `git-cmd.exe` is not a shell, it does not execute user input commands. The `cmd.exe` (shell you are using) do that. Learn about `PATH`.

> seems a bit more faster

Another unconfirmed statement. `cmd.exe` executing the **same commands** would show **same performance** in any case. Obviously, running **different** commands you would see different behavior.